# Namecheap + ddclient - 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: dynamic-dns, hosting, namecheap, ddclient

I just registered a domain on namecheap, and want to self-host through ddns. I have my host setting setup as:

```
@      127.0.0.1            A (address)
www    http://domain.com    HTTP Redirect
```

So clearly I'm trying to make it so that a www.domain.com redirects to domain.com, and the dynamic dns updates the latter. So my ddclient.conf file is:

```
## update time in 300 seconds                                                                                                          
daemon=300
## you can open this file with any text editor to see what is being sent                                                               
cache=/tmp/ddclient.cache
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid

## This line will get your public IP address if you're system is not directly connected                                                
## to the internet, such as behind a firewall/router                                                                                   
use=web, web=http://whatismyipaddress.com/, web-skip='Your IP address is'
protocol=namecheap
server=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com

## Your Domain name                                                                                                                    
login=foo.com
password=bar                                                                                                                         
@
```

Which I took off a tutorial online. When I try to connect to the site, a www.domain.com request redirects as intended, but the redirect or a direct domain.com request give a 400 Bad Request error. There's nothing in the nginx log, and this is my first rodeo with hosting my own server, so I don't really know where to start debugging this.

Answer (score 2):

This almost always happens with Namecheap's default DNS, as they don't update straight away, creating a misalignment when you enter the domain in the browser and the DNS attempts to resolve to where Namecheap first pointed it (its own parking page) when actually their system already has pointed it where you wanted it to go... they just didn't update the DNS (yet).

Resolution is almost always to have a cup of coffee and check back later!